# rsync- create daily backups that are deleted after 30 days?

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rsync

I am attempting to write a script in rsync to save daily backups in new directories named after the date they are created, before they are deleted 30 days after being created. The code below works, but it will quickly fill up my memory because the -u option will not see that several files in the directory structure already exist in a previous backup. Is there a better way to do this to preserve memory/bandwidth? I have had the --delete and --backup-dir options mentioned to me, but I have no idea how they would apply to this specific scenario.

```
#!/bin/bash

#User who's files are being backed up
BNAME=username
#directory to back up
BDIR=/home/username/BackThisUp
#directory to backup to
BackupDir=/var/home/username_local/BackupTo
#user
RUSER=$USER
#SSH Key
KEY=/var/home/username_local/.ssh
#Backupname
RBackup=`date +%F`
#Backup Server
BServ=backup.server
#Path
LPATH='Data for backup'
#date
DATE=`date +%F`

#make parent directory for backup
mkdir $BackupDir/$BNAME > /dev/null 2>&1

#Transfer new backups
rsync -avpHrz  -e "ssh -i $KEY" $BNAME@$BServ:$BDIR $BackupDir/$BNAME/$DATE


find $BackupDir/$BNAME -type d -ctime +30 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I might do somethign simpler.  Create a hash that only has the date's
 day in it.  For example, 8/11/2015 would hash to 11

Then do something like

```
# this number changes based on date.   
hash=`date +%d`
rm -rf backup_folder/$hash
# then recreate   backup_folder/$hash
```

You'll have around 30 days of backups.  You may want to zip/compress these folders, assuming you have 30 times the size of the folder available on the disk.